How to get the "space before" flag of PDF's with AFNumber_Format?
We use the AFNumber_Format to obtain the number information for text fields in PDFs. This allows us to distinguish which number style should be used for the display or which currency symbol should be displayed and whether this symbol should be displayed BEFORE or AFTER the number.
Adobe has some flags for this that can be set in their programme. Here you can define the 'symbol position'. Possible options are 'before with space', 'before without space', 'after with space' and 'after without space'. However, the flag in AFNumber_Format only specifies a Boolean value (before or after).
How can I read this with or without spaces from the AFNumber_Format?

Cool... so there are two options... the people don't understand what I am asking and vote me down for it or they are ignorant and vote me down without even thinking about explaining why... that is such an adult behaviour...

The space character has to be part of the strCurrency parameter. E.g.: ' €' or '€ '.
So the "flags" you see in Acrobat are not flags but are logic based on the strCurrency and bCurrencyPrepend parameter.

Thanks... I really overlooked this value three times... and three times I missed this little space in between all theese " and ...
